# PL/SQL function while loop returning 1 row only

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have tables(Customers,Pbasket and pp) with the following values inserted to the table

http://pastebin.com/eMUtLJn9

Basically I am tasked to create a function that finds all the product number(p#) purchased by the customer and I have to pass in the customer id(c#) as a input parameter;

This is my pl/sql script

http://pastebin.com/SqkY0P9N

I noticed that

there is no results returned for c#(100), which is correct.

but i noticed that for c#(101) and c#(102)

the result should return more than one p# but it only returns 1 result even though I had my while loop.

the output of my results

[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `function` you wrote was supposed to return **One** row only. And also, you had a `return` in your `LOOP`. So after *first iteration* the control is returned back.(leaving the `cursor` opened for ever)

**Create a TYPE of SQL Object**

```
create type my_numbers as table of NUMBER;
/
```

**FUNCTION returning a table!**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  purchased(cId IN NUMBER) 
RETURN my_numbers
IS  
    product VARCHAR2(45); 
    I NUMBER;
    v_my_list my_numbers := my_numbers();
    CURSOR CursorRow IS 
    SELECT p# 
    FROM customer c  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pbasket pb 
    ON c.c# = pb.c# 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pp pp 
    ON pb.whenfinalised = pp.whenfinalised
    WHERE c.c# = cId;
    CurrentPos CursorRow%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
    OPEN CursorRow;  
    I := 1;
    FETCH CursorRow into CurrentPos;
    LOOP
    EXIT WHEN CursorRow%NOTFOUND    
       v_my_list.EXTEND;
       v_my_list(I) := CurrentPos.p#;   
       I := I + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CursorRow;
    RETURN v_my_list;
END purchased;
/
```

**Final SELECT Query:**

```
select  * FROM TABLE(CAST(purchased(100) as my_numbers));
```

We can also use `Pipelined` functions (Slight modification needed) for *performance* over Large resultsets!